# Conditional compilation in ice40_synth using yosys?

Tags: command-line-interface, preprocessor, conditional-compilation, yosys

I'm currently compiling a bitstream for my project in a Makefile.

For the non-debug version of the build I use the following command:

```
yosys -p "synth_ice40 -blif $@ -top system" $^
```

And for the debug version I use:

```
yosys -p "verilog_defaults -add -DDEBUG; synth_ice40 -blif $@ -top system" $^
```

In the case of the debug build, the command completes, but `DEBUG is not defined when the verilog is read/parsed.

Does verilog_defaults apply to ice40_synth? And if not, is there a way to achieve this without replicating ice40_synth in a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source files specified as command line arguments are read before the commands in `-p` are executed. Thus, the `verilog_defaults -add` has no effect on parsing of `$^`.

One way of doing what you want is by manually setting the front-end + options to be used for command line arguments with `-f`:

```
yosys -f "verilog -DDEBUG" -p "synth_ice40 -blif $@ -top system" $^
```